# How to change Magento Order Status Default Flow?

Tags: magento

I learned lots about the relationship between Magento order state and status. I know how to add new state through config.xml file and assign new status to state.

But, How to change magento default status flow?

1,pending
2,pending payment
3,processing
4,completed

I believe this is a basic magento order status flow. But what if I want to add a new state between ppending payment and processing? For example, one site needs a payment review progress, the order status will be payment review once the payment done. Status will be only changed to porecessing after the review of the admin.

Where may I add this step? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Download this Zip-File: http://examples.oreilly.de/german_examples/magentopaiger/magento_fuer_entwickler.zip inside this file you will find some other zip-files, each represents a magento module. In your case have a look at the **Webkochshop_QualityAssurance-0.1.0.zip**.

Good Luck!